# How to sort data based on heirarchy

Tags: python, list, sorting

I have A list of strings as follows:

```
["a","aa", "b","bbb", "c", "a::b", "a::b::c", "a::b::d", "b:c"]
```

I want to sort this as

```
["a", "a::b", "a::b::c", "a:b::d", "aa", "b", "b:c", "bbb", "c"]
```

and so on.
Just for context.. the "::" acts as a delimiter which represents hierarchy. So, given a top-level object "a".. we first get "a::b", "a::b::c".. and all the children.. before going to next top-level object "aa".

What would be a good way to solve this in python (wondering if there is anything in collections or itertools library, I haven't been able to find appropriate method)?

Comment: Why don't you edit the code you have tried writing to solve this problem into your question?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's one way using just `sorted` and a custom key:

```
res = sorted(lst, key=lambda x: x.split('::'))

['a', 'a::b', 'a::b::c', 'a::b::d', 'aa', 'b', 'b:c', 'bbb', 'c']
```

Comment: Oh yeah, that's better than my method. Gets my vote. :)

Answer (score 3):

One way is to split each item at `::`, then sort, then join:

```
In [14]: l = ["a", "aa", "b", "bbb", "c", "a::b", "a::b::c", "a::b::d", "b::c"]

In [15]: map('::'.join, sorted(item.split('::') for item in l))
Out[15]: ['a', 'a::b', 'a::b::c', 'a::b::d', 'aa', 'b', 'b::c', 'bbb', 'c']
```

Comment: [Never use the characters ‘l’ (lowercase letter el), ‘O’ (uppercase letter oh), or ‘I’ (uppercase letter eye) as single character variable names.](http://pep8.org/#names-to-avoid)

Answer (score 0):

```
my_list = ["a","aa", "b","bbb", "c", "a::b", "a::b::c", "a::b::d", "b:c"]
my_result = sorted(my_list, key=lambda value: value.split('::'))
```

During sorting every list item will split, like: `"a::b::c"` will produce a list `["a","b","c"]`. Your actual sorting will be among `["a"],["aa"],["b"],["bbb"],["c"],["a","b"],["a","b","c"],["b","c]`. And sorting these lists the sort function returns your expected result.